# Invite friends to like a Facebook Fan Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

In my website I want to integrate the "Invite your friends to like this Page" similar to the Facebook Fan Page(Any), where people can search a friend and send an invite to like a page, after receiving and clicked that notification the user will be redirected to the Facebook Fan Page.

This what I do, by adding an App and Creating a Facebook Canvas in the [Developer Tools](https://developers.facebook.com/) and with this piece of code in my website:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
     appId      : '577325869064730',
     cookie     : true,
     xfbml      : true,  
     version    : 'v2.2' 
   });
};

function sendInvite() {
    FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'apprequests', 
            message: "I am inviting you to like my page"
        }, 
         function(response) {
           console.log(response);
        }
   );
}
```

It seems do the work, but the problem is it is not really the one I'm expecting because, It's not redirecting to the my Facebook Fan Page and the Facebook canvas URL only allowed a secure URL ("https") and doesn't allow the URL Facebook.

Is there a workaround for the redirection of the URL, rather than redirect to the declared URL in the Facebook canvas it should be pointed to my Facebook Fan Page. And the result should be the FULL Page of the Facebook Fan Page not in the Canvas.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

`apprequests` are for inviting friends to a game app on Facebook Canvas, not for inviting them to a Page (APP requests, hence the name). It will always redirect to the Canvas Page.

Better use the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) or [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog). Of course you don´t need https for those.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but I need a similar function on the invite where it only redirect to the fb fan page and not be publish on wall, just a notification.

Comment: Then use the message dialog.

Answer (score 0):

So far I was able to find a way to redirect it on the Facebook Fan Page, I just don't know if this is the correct solution:

In the website header, the one I declared in the Facebook Canvas URL:

I inserted this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  top.location = "www.facebook.com/fanpage"
</script>
```

It is now redirecting to the Facebook Fan Page.

Comment: you still need https for this, and you are actually abusing a facebook functionality for something else, and using canvas only to redirect is not allowed.